# do a bit of a level set on some suggestions -- meaning?

Tags: comprehension

Example ([short audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s163eAPEzSR1)):

> This is intended to be enough to get you moving with the core implementation of this idea. Just stay aware that you may have other classes in the same general area. So take a look to see if you've got any extra functionality options that'll be useful in the situation you're working in. Now, we still have a few more data structures to cover before we can regroup and **do a bit of a level set on some suggestions** and best practices with all of these.

Not sure how to understand that.

Comment: What is the subject of this clip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "set levels" is an expression from audio engineering, meaning to establish the settings for each input or output device which yield the best signal. It's used metaphorically here to mean review the possible contributions of a number of suggested functions or approaches and determine how they may be most effectively combined.